# why I get this error in Redshift for select insert into?

Tags: sql, select, insert, amazon-redshift

I copied this almost verbatim from another user's code for another DB system (SQL Server or Oracle), and I need to use in Redshift.

I created a table:

```
create table #Tablelist(
    tableid int identity(1,1)
    ,table_name varchar(50) not null
    ,primary key (table_name)
);
```

But when I run this:

```
insert into #Tablelist(table_name)
select distinct tablename
from pg_table_def
where tablename like '%some_pattern%';
```

redshift says:

```
 Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;
```

This part works fine:

```
select distinct tablename
from pg_table_def
where tablename like '%some_pattern%';
```

Answer (score 0):

The `identity`, `not null` and `primary key` constraints don't work in Redshift. Try to recreate the table without the constraints, and then try to insert the data.